# Adding toolbar to org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section via plugin.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am creating an Eclipse application. I created a Editor which has multiple `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section` and each Section has its own Toolbar which is currently declared inside Editor code only. What I need to do is to separate toolbar code from Editor code. What are best possible ways to separate toolbar code. Since there are several toolItems, the code of editor becomes complex. Can we define toolbar in `plugin.xml` for `org.eclipse.ui.forms.widgets.Section` ?
Currently adding toolbar to Section using following line of code:

```
ToolBar toolBar = new ToolBar(section, SWT.FLAT | SWT.RIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There aren't any extension points for Section.

You can use `ToolBarManager` for the tool bar. This lets you use `Action` classes (and other contribution items) in the tool bar. This lets you separate the code in to separate classes.

For example this is how the plugin.xml editor adds the 'alphabetic sort' button to the 'Required Plug-ins' section:

```
private void createSectionToolbar(Section section, FormToolkit toolkit) {
    ToolBarManager toolBarManager = new ToolBarManager(SWT.FLAT);

    ToolBar toolbar = toolBarManager.createControl(section);

    final Cursor handCursor = Display.getCurrent().getSystemCursor(SWT.CURSOR_HAND);
    toolbar.setCursor(handCursor);

    // Add sort action to the tool bar
    fSortAction = new SortAction(fImportViewer, PDEUIMessages.RequiresSection_sortAlpha, null, null, this);
    toolBarManager.add(fSortAction);

    toolBarManager.update(true);

    section.setTextClient(toolbar);
}
```

The sort code is in the separate `SortAction` class which extends `Action`.

`Section.setTextClient` puts the tool bar at the top right of the section title bar.